# Moving UIImages Back and Forth

Tags: xcode, swift

I don't know if I am doing this correctly. Please help me. I am trying to move the two images back and forth on the screen to make it look like it's closing and opening.

```
while (x>=1) {

    var customFrame1 = Laser1.frame
    if isImageLeftSide {
        customFrame1.origin.x = customFrame1.origin.x + 25
    }
    else {
        customFrame1.origin.x = customFrame1.origin.x - 25
    }

    var customFrame2 = Laser2.frame
    if isImageLeftSide {
        customFrame2.origin.x = customFrame2.origin.x + 25
    }
    else {
        customFrame2.origin.x = customFrame2.origin.x - 25
    }
        x += 1
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
while (x >= 1) {

    UIView.animateWithDuration(YOUR_ANIMATION_DURATION) {

        if isImageLeftSide {
            Laser1.frame.origin.x += 25
        } else {
            Laser1.frame.origin.x -= 25
        }
    }

    UIView.animateWithDuration(YOUR_ANIMATION_DURATION) {

        if isImageLeftSide {
            Laser2.frame.origin.x += 25
        } else {
            Laser2.frame.origin.x -= 25
        }
    }

    x += 1
}
```

Note: if `Laser1` and `Laser2` are properties of the class you'll have to use `self.Laser1` and `self.Laser2` in the animation blocks.

Comment: That still doesn't work. When I launch the app it freezes when I hit begin.

Comment: In that case get rid of the `while` statement and just run the animations when you "hit begin". `While` is causing it to execute over and over again rapidly, causing the crash.